# How to circumvent "Read-only file system" error on Docker version 0.11 or greater when running sysctl -w during an image build?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, docker, centos6

I'm trying to build an oracle-xe Docker image to be used on acceptance tests. The build process is aborted after trying to install Oracle XE 11g using the following command inside my Dockerfile:

```
RUN yum localinstall -y /tmp/oracle-xe-11.2.0-1.0.x86_64.rpm
```

If I disable the script execution during rpm installation Oracle XE doesn't work properly, so it is not an option.

Downgrading to Docker version 0.10 or under is not an option either, because I need the "host network" new feature.

Comment: Can you provide an example that triggers the problem in the title without requiring to install Oracle? Also, which is your base image? (Might be OS-related). Ideally, a minimal Dockerfile would be best.

Comment: Same problem here from base centos:6.4 or centos:latest (centos6). Moreover there seems to be an issue related to a recent kernel update (3.15.3). It works with docker 0.8 and kernel 3.11.10.

Comment: I am also having similar problem.